# Will the version of Diablo 2 included with the Collectors Edition of Diablo 3 run on modern Mac OS X?

Tags: macos, diablo-ii

The collectors Edition of Diablo 3 includes a 4GB USB drive preloaded with Diablo 2 and Lord of Destruction.

Will this version of the game run on a modern Intel Mac running OS X 10.7 without modifications, virtualisation or other third party software?

I have read that Blizzard stopped supporting Diablo 2 on the Mac after Apple removed [Rosetta](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rosetta_%28software%29) from the OS, but does this also mean they would send out copies of Diablo 2 that won't run on a Mac?

Comment: Now I'm wondering if the CE will give to you the D2/D2LoD in the online version (store/BattleNet account) as well.

Comment: @Michel - We will have to find out.  If they provide you a cd-key you can add it yourself.  Since Blizzard old installers required a cd-key to even install, and they are unlikely to go repackage an old game into a new installer, its very likely there will be at least a peice of paper with the authentication codes on it.  I will have to look at my Starcraft 2 Collectors Edition's flashdrive to figure out how they handled the digital copy of Starcraft 1.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

As of 2017, **yes**, [Blizzard supports](http://web.archive.org/web/20170430093136/https://us.battle.net/support/en/article/Diablo-II-System-Requirements) *D2* on the latest macOS (10.12).

At the time of release, **no**, the included *Diablo II* + *LoD* [did not run on OS X Lion (10.7)](https://web.archive.org/web/20131231185256/https://us.battle.net/support/en/article/diablo-ii-minimum-system-requirements). The soulstone drive edition was no different than Blizzard's latest digital download, which worked with Mac OS 10.3.9 through 10.6 Snow Leopard (and Windows 2000 through Windows 7) but not 10.7 Lion.<sup>[1](https://us.battle.net/support/en/article/Diablo-II-System-Requirements#c-tab-mac)</sup> They also had no immediate plans to support it.<sup>[2](https://web.archive.org/web/20140122201421/http://us.battle.net/support/en/article/playing-older-blizzard-titles-on-mac-os-x-10-7-lion) [3](https://web.archive.org/web/20140122201517/https://us.battle.net/support/en/article/diablo-ii-compatibility-issues-and-workarounds)</sup>

So, yes, the Collector's Edition USB soulstone shipped without modern support for *D2*, though it runs just fine in Parallels and Boot Camp on a MacBook Air, and now runs on the latest Macs.

Comment: Technically, Snow Leopard is emulating Diablo 2 via Rosetta.

Comment: Is this still true?

Comment: @KolobCanyon updated for ya

Comment: @Wolf I tested downloading their installer for mac from Battle.net on OS X 10.10 (Yosemite). Diablo II worked, but when I install Diablo II LOD, the screen flickers when i launch it... Tried reinstalling 3 times and same result everytime... even after grabbing new installers from the site (initially I thought it may be corrupt). Help? Should I ask this in a new question?

Answer (score 2):

According to Blizzard, they do not support the "Classic" version of the game anymore. This is the version that is found on the CD and would be the ones that run under Rosetta. As a solution, they provide a downloadable Intel based client to replace the CD version. My feeling is the version you will get on the USB stick will be that Intel client and not the older "classic" one.

http://us.battle.net/support/en/article/mac-error-classic-environment-not-supported

Comment: I would like to know why this has a down vote. I don't like it when people down vote and don't say why...

Comment: It doesn't answer the question in any definitive way. The article linked is for a separate (but sometimes confused) topic: classic mode is a way to run OS9 apps on early OSX versions, the actual problem deals with Rosetta running the "newer" Carbon version on Lion installs.

Comment: There is no way to "definitively" answer this question until after May 15th when someone actually gets the Collector's Edition and confirms which version is on the USB drive and if it runs on Lion. Rosetta does not run under ANY version of Lion so we can only speculate based on the current clients available.

Comment: @GregDemetrick My issue is that you don't even answer the question, you just speculate on which existing version will ship with the CE (probably correctly). And in either of these cases, the answer to the question "will it run on lion?" is **No**.

Comment: That is a very valid point @authenticgeek but instead of just down voting, why did you not also answer the question which you obviously knew the answer to? (I do realize this may push this comment thread to meta but am just curious)

Comment: @GregDemetrick I actually do not know the answer. It's entirely possible (though unlikely) that Blizzard put a previously unseen Lion-compatible version on that CE thumbdrive. I don't have one and won't speculate on what's on it.